# Filtering 'current-menu-item' class to use 'active' instead

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming, twitter-bootstrap

I am building a custom theme based on the [Roots Theme](https://roots.io/) which now uses Twitter Bootstrap as a framework.

It uses a custom 'walker' for navigation so I can't just filter it through PHP in the Header.php.

```
  <nav>
    <?php 
      wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location' => 'primary_navigation',
                        'walker' => new Roots_Nav_Walker()
                        ));
    ?>
  </nav>
```

I know how to add arguments from my [research on the Codex](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/) but this does not tell me how to add a filter on the 'current-menu-item' class. The reason I want to do this is so I can easily switch between the different navigation styles that Bootstrap offers by default.

I also do not want to just overwrite the CSS to make the rules for 'active' apply to 'current-menu-item'.

Ideally I would like to change it in the roots-cleanup.php where the 'walker' is created.

Relevant Code:

```
class Roots_Nav_Walker extends Walker_Nav_Menu {
  function check_current($val) {
    return preg_match('/(current-)/', $val);
  }

  function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth, $args) {
    global $wp_query;
    $indent = ($depth) ? str_repeat("\t", $depth) : '';

    $slug = sanitize_title($item->title);

    $class_names = $value = '';
    $classes = empty($item->classes) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;

    $classes = array_filter($classes, array(&$this, 'check_current'));

    $class_names = join(' ', apply_filters('nav_menu_css_class', array_filter($classes), $item));
    $class_names = $class_names ? ' class="' . esc_attr($class_names) . '"' : '';

    $id = apply_filters('nav_menu_item_id', 'menu-' . $slug, $item, $args);
    $id = strlen($id) ? ' id="' . esc_attr( $id ) . '"' : '';

    $output .= $indent . '<li' . $id . $class_names . '>';

    $attributes  = ! empty($item->attr_title) ? ' title="'  . esc_attr($item->attr_title) .'"' : '';
    $attributes .= ! empty($item->target)     ? ' target="' . esc_attr($item->target    ) .'"' : '';
    $attributes .= ! empty($item->xfn)        ? ' rel="'    . esc_attr($item->xfn       ) .'"' : '';
    $attributes .= ! empty($item->url)        ? ' href="'   . esc_attr($item->url       ) .'"' : '';

    $item_output = $args->before;
    $item_output .= '<a'. $attributes .'>';
    $item_output .= $args->link_before . apply_filters('the_title', $item->title, $item->ID) . $args->link_after;
    $item_output .= '</a>';
    $item_output .= $args->after;

    $output .= apply_filters('walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args);
  }
}

class Roots_Navbar_Nav_Walker extends Walker_Nav_Menu {
  function check_current($val) {
    return preg_match('/(current-)|active|dropdown/', $val);
  }

  function start_lvl(&$output, $depth) {
    $output .= "\n<ul class=\"dropdown-menu\">\n";
  }

  function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth, $args) {
    global $wp_query;
    $indent = ($depth) ? str_repeat("\t", $depth) : '';

    $slug = sanitize_title($item->title);

    $li_attributes = '';
    $class_names = $value = '';

    $classes = empty($item->classes) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;
    if ($args->has_children) {
      $classes[]      = 'dropdown';
      $li_attributes .= 'data-dropdown="dropdown"';
    }
    $classes[] = ($item->current) ? 'active' : '';
    $classes = array_filter($classes, array(&$this, 'check_current'));

    $class_names = join(' ', apply_filters('nav_menu_css_class', array_filter($classes), $item));
    $class_names = $class_names ? ' class="' . esc_attr($class_names) . '"' : '';

    $id = apply_filters('nav_menu_item_id', 'menu-' . $slug, $item, $args);
    $id = strlen($id) ? ' id="' . esc_attr( $id ) . '"' : '';

    $output .= $indent . '<li' . $id . $class_names . $li_attributes . '>';

    $attributes  = ! empty($item->attr_title) ? ' title="'  . esc_attr($item->attr_title) .'"'    : '';
    $attributes .= ! empty($item->target)     ? ' target="' . esc_attr($item->target    ) .'"'    : '';
    $attributes .= ! empty($item->xfn)        ? ' rel="'    . esc_attr($item->xfn       ) .'"'    : '';
    $attributes .= ! empty($item->url)        ? ' href="'   . esc_attr($item->url       ) .'"'    : '';
    $attributes .= ($args->has_children)      ? ' class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"' : '';

    $item_output = $args->before;
    $item_output .= '<a'. $attributes .'>';
    $item_output .= $args->link_before . apply_filters('the_title', $item->title, $item->ID) . $args->link_after;
    $item_output .= ($args->has_children) ? ' <b class="caret"></b>' : '';
    $item_output .= '</a>';
    $item_output .= $args->after;

    $output .= apply_filters('walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args);
  }
  function display_element($element, &$children_elements, $max_depth, $depth = 0, $args, &$output) {
    if (!$element) { return; }

    $id_field = $this->db_fields['id'];

    // display this element
    if (is_array($args[0])) {
      $args[0]['has_children'] = !empty($children_elements[$element->$id_field]);
    } elseif (is_object($args[0])) {
      $args[0]->has_children = !empty($children_elements[$element->$id_field]);
    }
    $cb_args = array_merge(array(&$output, $element, $depth), $args);
    call_user_func_array(array(&$this, 'start_el'), $cb_args);

    $id = $element->$id_field;

    // descend only when the depth is right and there are childrens for this element
    if (($max_depth == 0 || $max_depth > $depth+1) && isset($children_elements[$id])) {
      foreach ($children_elements[$id] as $child) {
        if (!isset($newlevel)) {
          $newlevel = true;
          // start the child delimiter
          $cb_args = array_merge(array(&$output, $depth), $args);
          call_user_func_array(array(&$this, 'start_lvl'), $cb_args);
        }
        $this->display_element($child, $children_elements, $max_depth, $depth + 1, $args, $output);
      }
      unset($children_elements[$id]);
    }

    if (isset($newlevel) && $newlevel) {
      // end the child delimiter
      $cb_args = array_merge(array(&$output, $depth), $args);
      call_user_func_array(array(&$this, 'end_lvl'), $cb_args);
    }

    // end this element
    $cb_args = array_merge(array(&$output, $element, $depth), $args);
    call_user_func_array(array(&$this, 'end_el'), $cb_args);
  }
}

function roots_nav_menu_args($args = '') {
  $args['container']  = false;
  $args['depth']      = 2;
  $args['items_wrap'] = '<ul class="nav nav-tabs">%3$s</ul>';
  if (!$args['walker']) {
    $args['walker'] = new Roots_Nav_Walker();
  }
  return $args;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found the answer, maybe not relevant anymore, but

update roots and you will find in

lib/cleanup.php

```
roots_wp_nav_menu()
```

it's in there now

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem I had solve it this way i dont know weather it is correct or wrong.. but it works... :)

in the header.php

```
<div class="navbar">
   <div class="navbar-inner">
        <?php

        $defaults = array(
            'theme_location' => 'header-menu',
            'menu' => '',
            'container' => 'div',
            'container_class' => 'container',
            'container_id' => '',
            'menu_class' => 'nav',
            'menu_id' => '',
            'echo' => true,
            'fallback_cb' => 'wp_page_menu',
            'before' => '',
            'after' => '',
            'link_before' => '',
            'link_after' => '',
            'items_wrap' => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>',
            'depth' => 2,
            'walker' => ''
        );

        wp_nav_menu($defaults);
        ?>
  </div></div>
```

and in the footer add a jquery function :

```
<script>
        $(function(){
           $('.current-menu-item').addClass('active'); 
        });
</script>
```